# Extract zipped files needs persmission

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy xlsm file to zip file using FileCopy method. After that I need to extract the zipped files to Temp path
The following code works fine just for the first time

```
Sub Test()
Dim tmpPdf      As String
Dim oApp        As Object
Dim i           As Long

Dim tmpPath       As Variant
tmpPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Temp"

Dim excelFile     As Variant
excelFile = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\New.xlsm"

Dim zipName       As Variant
zipName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\New.zip"

On Error Resume Next
    Kill zipName

    With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        .DeleteFolder tmpPath
        .CreateFolder tmpPath
        Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:03")
    End With

    'Kill tmpPath & "\*.*"

    FileCopy excelFile, zipName
    'If Err.Number <> 0 Then MsgBox "Unable To Copy": Exit Sub
On Error GoTo 0
Set oApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

UnZipFile zipName, tmpPath


MsgBox "Done...", 64

End Sub

Sub UnZipFile(zippedFileFullName As Variant, unzipToPath As Variant)
Dim shellApp As Object

Set shellApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
shellApp.Namespace(unzipToPath).CopyHere shellApp.Namespace(zippedFileFullName).items
End Sub
```

But with a second attempt I got an error like that
[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Try saving to `Environ$("temp")` instead?

Comment: I tried that but I got run-time error 91 'Object variable or With block variable not set' at this line `shellApp.Namespace(unzipToPath).CopyHere shellApp.Namespace(zippedFileFullName).items`

Comment: `tmpPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Temp"` should be `tmpPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Temp\"`

Comment: @alowflyingpig I already tried this but I got the same error ..